# Website speed diagnosis - expression engine

Tags: performance, expressionengine, pagespeed

We can't seem to be given any answers as to why our website is so slow and continues to get slower. Can anyone tell me why http://www.kaboodle.com.au is slow and what we can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

See report: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.kaboodle.com.au/yc1I3YXZ

I will break it down for you:

1. Scale and optimize the images you have. use photoshop "save for web", jpeg mini or if you use wordpress EWWWW image optimizer. Some images are much bigger than their display ratio on website.
2. Addthis can sometimes slow down websites. Try moving it to load on bottom
3. Your most problematic loading element is the dns. check with your dns provider if they can fix it. Anyway you should use cdn like CLOUDFLARE or MAXCDN

Do all these and I think your page will load much much faster. You can get to 2.7-3.5s easily